# ElasticSearch finds System.NullReferenceException, but not NullReferenceException - why?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a basic ELK stack, where multiple machines push logs to an ElasticSearch (ES) server and I inspect them using Kibana.

My problem is that I can see plenty of `System.NullReferenceException` matches, but none of `NullReferenceException`, which puzzles me greatly.

Here is the query I am trying to run:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "message": "NullReferenceException"
    }
  }
}
```

And the result is:

```
{
  "took": 47,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1681,
    "successful": 1681,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

However, if I use the following query:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "message": "System.NullReferenceException"
    }
  }
}
```

I get:

```
{
  "took": 31,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1681,
    "successful": 1681,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 12796,
    "max_score": 1.7968642,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "logs-good-qa_849-2016.05.05",
        "_type": "MobileWebService",
        "_id": "28327d702db62623059027479162a3d73ef909f6",
        "_score": 1.7968642,
        "_source": {
          "@timestamp": "2016-05-05T19:04:20.741Z",
          "message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object. \r\nSystem.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of 
...
```

The message column seems to be analyzed. If I request the mapping:

```
GET logs-good-qa_849-2016.05.05/_mapping/MobileWebService
```

I get back this:

```
# GET logs-good-qa_849-2016.05.05/_mapping/MobileWebService
{
  "logs-good-qa_849-2016.05.05": {
    "mappings": {
      "MobileWebService": {
        "properties": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          "@version": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "host": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "level": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "logger": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "message": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "path": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "qa_build": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "tags": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "ts": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

From which I conclude that the message field should have been broken by the word delimiters and indexed respectively. As far as I know `.` is a word delimiter, so I do not understand what is going on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to analyze the content of the `message` field:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/accounts_2016_dev/_analyze?pretty' -d 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object. \r\nSystem.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of'
```

One of the tokens we get is the following:

```
 {
    "token" : "nsystem.nullreferenceexception",
    "start_offset" : 57,
    "end_offset" : 87,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 12
  }
```

As you can see the dot is not used as a word delimiter since there is no space behind it. More generally, analyzing `test.dot` will produce a single token `test.dot`, while analyzing `test. dot` (with 1+ space behind the dot) will produce two tokens `test` and `dot`.

For this reason, you cannot match `NullReferenceException` only.

Comment: That is an excellent explanation. Thank you. So, I suppose I need to add "." to the word delimiters and re-index everything. Can you suggest the best way to do so?

Comment: I'm not certain just adding `.` is a good idea as you'd run the risk of splitting decimal numbers, too, e.g. `3.4` would get split into `3` and `4` and that's probably not what you want. The best way to achieve what you want would be to create a custom analyzer which leverages [the ngram token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenfilter.html) and/or [the edgeNgram token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenfilter.html) in order to produce prefixes and suffixes for each token.

Comment: Custom analyzer? Sounds scary. I am starting to think maybe I am asking for too much, even though I do not believe that my desire to search for `NullReferenceException` as-is is too much. Am I missing something (I might, since I am very new to this whole business of ELK) ?

Comment: Not scary at all :-) It's a common practice to define [custom analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html) and it's not that difficult once you know what you want/need to be able to query. Have a quick look and don't hesitate if you have questions.

Comment: I am considering an alternative approach - adding a tag, which is the exception name. So, I modify the grok filter to add a tag and run an update to add the tag to already existing records. Can you advise on this approach?

Comment: Of course, if you're willing to enrich the document at indexing time with some additional info gathered from some special treatments on existing fields, that would work too. If you have that info readily available, by all means, you should use it.